# Gracefully switch domain from App Engine service to Cloud Run

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a service running in App Engine, which has custom domain mapped to it.
We are in a process of migrating this service from App Engine to Cloud Run.
Thus, we would like to switch domain mapping from App Engine to Cloud Run.
We've tried doing that in our staging environment and discovered that such switching causes some downtime of our service (about 10-15 minutes).
Is it possible to avoid such a downtime and migrate traffic/switch domain gracefully without downtime?

Just for information, in our App Engine domain is mapped through deploying `dispatch.yaml` file.
In Cloud Run we enable domain for our service through following link: https://console.cloud.google.com/run/domains?project=<project_name>&supportedpurview=project

Comment: AFAIK you will have downtime. The issue is that the domain mapping is managed by the GFE (Google Frontend). You must delete and reissue custom domain mappings. One way to decrease the downtime is to make the DNS resource record TTL value small, such as 60 seconds. Once the remapping succeeds, change the TTL back to a normal value such as 86400 (one day).

Comment: Does john answer help to solve the issue?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni we haven't tried yet.

Comment: Can you try and revert back with the result? Meanwhile you can check the [document1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains) and [document2](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) mentioned and [@Sandeep Vokkareni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18265702/sandeep-vokkareni) shared,

It potentially will have downtime. The issue is that the domain mapping is managed by the GFE (Google Frontend). You must delete and reissue [custom domain mappings](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update:%7E:text=in%20some%20cases%20it%20can%20take%20up%20to%20several%20hours). One way to decrease the downtime is to make the DNS resource record [TTL value small](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en#TTL:%7E:text=you%20can%20set%20a%20shorter%20TTL), such as 60 seconds. Once the remapping succeeds, change the TTL back to a normal value such as 86400 (one day).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We've migrated traffic during night time without changing TTL. But I will try your way if we ever need to do that again.

Answer (score 0):

We also need to switch from App Engine to Cloud Run.

From this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/run/custom-domain-to-cloud-load-balancing I'm pretty sure that we can do the migration without any downtime.

In the guide, it's written:

> Note that the Cloud Load Balancing documentation has similar instructions for creating a Google-managed SSL certificate, but the instructions there use load balancer authorization, which requires downtime for your App Engine service that could last up to several hours. For more information, see Domain authorization for Google-managed certificates.

From my understanding, using a certificate with DNS authorization allows creating it in advance before having to really change the final DNS record.

I'll try that in the next few days, I'll update my comment once I've done it to tell if it works or not.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I could finally give this a try and as expected it works.

To resume, to migrate your DNS record from GAE to GCR, you have to:

- create a SSL certificate with a DNS authorization in GCP
- add the relevant CNAME entry in your DNS provider
- wait for the certificate to be provisionned
- create a load balancer and attach the certificate to the forwarding rule
- ensure LB with GCR is working as expected (you can modify your hosts file to force your computer to hit your domain with LB's IP)

At this point if you want to perform the switch, as you cannot have a CNAME and A DNS records for the same DNS record, you need to quickly remove the CNAME, add the A entry with LB's IP. Until DNS propagation completes, there should be no downtime